# Domain controller same dns as website

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, website

I have the problem, that our website has the same name as our domain. Our website is hosted by an external comapny. Now all computer in our network can't access our website, because the DNS always resolve the ip to the domain controller. Is there a method, that the DNSs server do resolve all requests for port 80 to another IP-Address (In my case, the extern ip address)?

Thank you!

Comment: "our website has the same name as our domain". Can you please demonstrate it by an example?

Comment: Our domain is `abcd.com`, and our domain also has the name `abcd.com`. If i type abcd.com in any browser, the domain controller server ip gets resolved.

Comment: Possible to map using a SRV record, but not recommended.

Else you can create a host (A) record in the name www and IP, the website IP.

Comment: Ok, so that `abcd.com` resolve the dc ip and `www.abcd.com` resolve the website ip?

Comment: Exactly.. If you've a load balancer in between, you may be able to create a rule to convert abcd.com requests to www.abcd.com

Comment: @serverstackqns we have no load balancer, but i will try your solution, thank you!

Comment: Let me know how it goes..

Comment: Add an A record in your AD DNS zone for www for the website ip address and tell your users not to use the naked domain when going to the website.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a lab or something non-productive, it would be also possible installing a forward proxy using ARR on the domain controllers to get them forwarding all Port 80 traffic to the external Web servers. [Read this Forum post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1208016.aspx?Configure%20ARR%203%200%20on%20Windows%202012%20R2%20as%20Forward%20Proxy%20for%20Internet%20Access) to get an idea of how to implement that.

ARR (application request routing) [is also available](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee683903%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for Server 2008.

Comment: I will think about your idea, but the system is very productive :)